# How to change the language in Show fixes suggestions in VSCode

Tags: language, display-settings, default-settings, visual-studio-code

I've recently discovered that despite all my VS Code installation is in English, and the default language in settings is English, I get Polish language in "Show fixes":

[Polish language in "Show fixes" popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVmMK.png)

Any idea where can I change the language of this feature?

It's not the default language in *locale.json*. Also I don't have any language pack installed.

As for installed extensions, I've got C#, Code Runner, ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets, Prettier-Code formatter, Python, Python-autopep8, Simple React Snippets, Visual Studio IntelliCode - Preview. My OS: Windows 10.

I've got no language packs installed in VSCode, but my Windows 10 is in Polish. Could that be the case?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  What language packs do you have installed on the OS?  Instead of submitting a comment, edit your question, and include the necessary information required to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to sort of bug in OmniSharp VS Code extension which is C# (ms-vscode.csharp).
There is workaround described by the authors ([link here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2513#issuecomment-423270085)).

You need to remove the Polish translations from this extension.
The translation sits in the following folder (in Windows):

*C:\Users\YourUserNameFolder.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9.omnisharp\1.34.9\pl*

Remove all dll files starting with *'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis'*

(Please notice that some folder names in the path might vary due to different versions)

The path ends with folder name 'pl' which stands for Polish version. By analogy you can find different folder and remove translations for other language.

Comment: does not really work for me and vscodes starts with an error msg noticing the missing files